# Все ли запятые нужны?

Tags: пунктуация

"Должна же, действительно, у меня быть какая-то своя, личная позиция по этому, безусловно важному, вопросу".
Надо ли обособлять "безусловно важному" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь  нужно обособить БЕЗУСЛОВНО ВАЖНОМУ как уточняющий член предложения: по этому (а именно какому?), безусловно важному, вопросу. 
Если же не обособлять выражение БЕЗУСЛОВНО ВАЖНОМУ, то возникают трудности со словом БЕЗУСЛОВНО, которое иногда употребляется как вводное, и тогда только слово "безусловно" надо выделить запятыми; а иногда как обстоятельство, выраженное наречием, и тогда выделять "безусловно" не нужно. Так что первый вариант с обособлением БЕЗУСЛОВНО ВАЖНОМУ, я думаю, наиболее приемлемый.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с Екатериной. Но в данном предложении мне непонятно разделение запятой слов "своя" и "личная". Имхо, здесь запятая либо не нужна, либо надо обособить уточняющее определение "личная".

Comment: Я с Вами согласна.